# Dynatree options linking to dropdown values

Tags: jquery, dynatree

Is there a way to Link different dropdown values fetched from database to **dynatree**?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Link different dropdown values dynatree'?

Comment: I know the different branches(sub folders) can be linked to a root(root folder). Iam looking for a way to make different subfolder names to be shown in a dropdown which needs to be linked to root folder.